Showing all procedure names called within the procedure in order of execution
I have 4 procedures, pr_x is my main procedure
and in
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_X AS
    v_first_name VARCHAR2(100);
    pr_y(v_first_name);
    pr_z(v_first_name);

are called in order
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_y AS
    v_first_name VARCHAR2(100);
    pr_t(v_first_name);



pr_t is called inside pr_y.
I want these procedures to be shown in the order they run, but I get the following result with this code.
WITH procedure_calls (called_procedure, depth) AS (
    SELECT 
        referenced_name AS called_procedure,
        1 AS depth
    FROM 
        all_dependencies
    WHERE 
        name = 'PR_X'
        AND type = 'PROCEDURE'
        AND referenced_type = 'PROCEDURE'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        ad.referenced_name AS called_procedure,
        pc.depth + 1 AS depth
    FROM 
        all_dependencies ad
    INNER JOIN 
        procedure_calls pc ON ad.name = pc.called_procedure
    WHERE 
        ad.type = 'PROCEDURE'
        AND ad.referenced_type = 'PROCEDURE'
)
SELECT 
    called_procedure,
    depth,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY depth) AS execution_order
FROM 
    procedure_calls
WHERE 
    called_procedure LIKE 'PR%';


I tried this solution but not what i want it



CALLED_PROCEDURE
DEPTH
EXECUTION_ORDER




PR_Y
1
1


PR_Z
1
2


PR_T
2
3



I want this result



CALLED_PROCEDURE
DEPTH
EXECUTION_ORDER




PR_Y
1
1


PR_T
2
2


PR_Z
1
3




Do not spam tags of lots of different RDBMS. Only tag the one that you are actually using.

You need to add back a tag that is for the one and only RDBMS you're using. And tag spamming is a good way to get your post closed and downvoted. Tags have relevance and meaning here. Also, you're wasting both your time and ours when you use the wrong tag and someone answers your question, only to find out that answer does not work for the RDBMS you're actually using. You should also read Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question.

Also, read your own code. It does not match the output you want to obtain. You have an ORDER BY on DEPTH which is why it's producing the output it is now. If you want it sorted differently, change your ORDER BY.

Oracle:
With sample procedures:
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_t AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Running pr_t');
END pr_t;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_y AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Running pr_y');
    pr_t;
END pr_y;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_z AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Running pr_z');
END pr_z;
--
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE PROCEDURE pr_x AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Running pr_x');
    pr_y;
    pr_z;
END pr_x;

Running pr_x for test:
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Begin
    pr_x;
End;
/

/*  R e s u l t :
Running pr_x
Running pr_y
Running pr_t
Running pr_z

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.        */

One option could be using recursive cte taking care of posible multiple calls and depths deeper in the execution order:
WITH 
    procedure_calls ( OWNER, PROC_NAME, TEXT, LINE, PROC_POSITION, REFERENCED_NAME, DEPTH, EXEC_ORDER) AS 
      ( Select      o.OWNER, o.OBJECT_NAME as PROC_NAME, 
                    s.TEXT, s.LINE, 
                    InStr(Upper(s.TEXT), d.REFERENCED_NAME) as PROC_POSITION,
                    d.REFERENCED_NAME, 
                    1 as DEPTH,
                    Row_Number() Over(Partition By o.OBJECT_NAME Order By s.LINE) as EXEC_ORDER
        From        all_objects o 
        Inner Join  all_source s ON(s.OWNER = o.OWNER And s.NAME = o.OBJECT_NAME)
        Inner Join  all_dependencies d ON(d.OWNER = o.OWNER And d.NAME = o.OBJECT_NAME)
        Where       o.OWNER = d.REFERENCED_OWNER And 
                    o.OBJECT_NAME = 'PR_X' And 
                    o.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' And
                    InStr(Upper(s.TEXT), d.REFERENCED_NAME) > 0 
     UNION ALL
        Select      o2.OWNER, o2.OBJECT_NAME as PROC_NAME, 
                    s2.TEXT, s2.LINE, 
                    InStr(Upper(s2.TEXT), d2.REFERENCED_NAME) as PROC_POSITION,
                    d2.REFERENCED_NAME, 
                    DEPTH + 1 as DEPTH,
                    pc.EXEC_ORDER + (pc.DEPTH / 10) AS EXEC_ORDER
        From        procedure_calls pc, all_objects o2 
        Inner Join  all_source s2 ON(s2.OWNER = o2.OWNER And s2.NAME = o2.OBJECT_NAME)
        Inner Join  all_dependencies d2 ON(d2.OWNER = o2.OWNER And d2.NAME = o2.OBJECT_NAME)
        Where       o2.OWNER = d2.REFERENCED_OWNER And 
                    o2.OBJECT_NAME = pc.REFERENCED_NAME And 
                    o2.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' And
                    InStr(Upper(s2.TEXT), d2.REFERENCED_NAME) > 0 
      )

--     M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT    pc.REFERENCED_NAME as CALLED_PROCEDURE, 
          pc.DEPTH, 
          Row_Number() Over(Order By pc.EXEC_ORDER, pc.LINE) as EXECUTION_ORDER
FROM      procedure_calls pc
WHERE     InStr(Upper(pc.TEXT), pc.PROC_NAME) = 0 And InStr(Upper(pc.TEXT), pc.REFERENCED_NAME) > 0
ORDER BY  EXEC_ORDER, LINE

/*      R e s u l t :
CALLED_PROCEDURE                    DEPTH EXECUTION_ORDER
------------------------------ ---------- ---------------
PR_Y                                    1               1
PR_T                                    2               2
PR_Z                                    1               3   */
~~

